General solution for $ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2} $
My AP Calculus BC class doesn't teach trig substitution, but the homework had a problem that required it. I experimented with trig substitution until I figured it out enough to solve the problem. Then, I tried to find the generalized solution for all values of a and got the following result:

$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2} = \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{2a^3} + \frac{x}{2a^2(x^2 + a^2)} + C$$

My attempt:
Using the substitution $ x = a\tan(\theta), \theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ and applying the identity $ \tan^2(\theta) + 1 = \sec^2(\theta) $ gives:
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(a^2\sec^2(\theta))^2}=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{a^4\sec^4 (\theta)}$$
since $ x = a\tan(\theta)\implies\mathrm dx=a\sec^2(\theta)\mathrm d\theta $.
Substituting this into the integral above and pulling out the $a$ terms gives $$\frac{1}{a^3}\int\frac{\sec^2(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta}{\sec^4(\theta)} = \frac{1}{a^3}\int\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\sec^2(\theta)} = \frac{1}{a^3}\int\cos^2(\theta)\mathrm d\theta $$
Using the identity $\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2} $ gives
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{a^3} \int\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)\mathrm d\theta}{2}&=\frac{1}{2a^3}\int\mathrm d\theta + \frac{1}{2a^3} + \int\cos(2\theta)\mathrm d\theta\\&= \frac{\theta}{2a^3} + \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4a^3}+C\end{align}$$
Since $x=a\tan(\theta)\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)\implies\theta = \arctan(\frac{x}{a})$, which means that the left portion simplifies to $\frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{a})}{2a^3}$
To find simplify the right side, we can use the identity $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$. If $\tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{a}$, $$\sec^2(\theta) = 1+\tan^2(\theta) = 1 + \frac{x^2}{a^2}= \frac{x^2+a^2}{a^2}$$ This means that $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$
$\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$, so $$\begin{align}\sin(\theta)&= \sqrt{1-\cos^2(\theta)}\\&= \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{a^2+x^2}}\\&= \sqrt{\frac{a^2+x^2-a^2}{a^2+x^2}}\\&= \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\end{align}$$
Plugging these values into $ 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$ gives $$2\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}  = \frac{2xa}{x^2+a^2}$$
Substituting this into $\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4a^3}$ gives $$\frac{2xa}{4a^3(x^2+a^2)} = \frac{x}{2a^2(x^2+a^2)}$$
This means that the final answer is $$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2} = \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{2a^3} + \frac{x}{2a^2(x^2 + a^2)} + C$$ assuming I made no mistakes. I am not super familiar with trig substitution and want to make sure my logic is sound here.

Having $a^2$ instead of $a$ will make this less messy. I don’t know what the point of your post is. You can check that your result is correct/incorrect by differentiating (or looking at a table of integrals or at Wolfram Alpha).

I think it would help if you showed your attempt. You may as well use $a^2$ as suggested by Ted.

Wolfram Alpha, as Ted suggested, does give the same answer, so it's probably correct.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119270/help-evaluating-int-fracdxx2-a22 for some approaches without trig substitution.

Note that while performing substitutions like trig, square roots, you need to specify the domain of the new variable so that the substitution be bijective, eg: for $x=a\tan\theta$, the best choice is $\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2.\frac\pi2\right)$. Also, $\tan^{-1}(\tan x)=x\iff x\in\left(-\frac\pi2.\frac\pi2\right)$.

Short MathJax tips: $1.$ For big equations, use $$...$$, not $...$. $2.$ Include the $=$ sign in the MathJax code. $3.$ For a series of equalities, use the environment align.

Also, observe that for $\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, $\sec\theta=|\sec\theta|=\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}$, so the signs of $x$ and $\sin\theta$ must be the same, that's why $\sin\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$ which you seem to have assumed implicitly. Apart from these small issues, your solution is perfectly fine.

Hint:
Substitute $x=\sqrt{a}\tan(\theta)$
Now, the given integral is $$\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a)^{2}}\mathrm dx$$
Now, if I substitute $x=\sqrt{a}\tan(\theta)$ then I will get $\mathrm dx=\sqrt{a}\sec^{2}(\theta)\mathrm d\theta$
Therefore $$\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a)^{2}}\mathrm dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{a}\sec^{2}(\theta)}{a^{2}\sec^{4}(\theta)}\mathrm d\theta$$
$$\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a)^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{a^\frac{3}{2}}\int\frac{1}{\sec^{2}(\theta)}\mathrm d\theta$$
Now, write $\frac{1}{\sec^{2}(\theta)}=\cos^{2}(\theta)$
And finally write $$\cos^{2}(\theta)=\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}$$
Now integrate.
Hope you can do it now.

this is the same as OP's method

Actually I got confused. Because in the title OP mentioned $\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a)^{2}}$ and in the body he mentioned $\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{2}}$. So, I really got confused

The OP is asking to check their solution.

@Mathematics, I apologize for changing the notation. Someone suggested that I change a to a^2, and I couldn't edit the question title.

It's Fine @Befunge. "To Err is Human".

@Befunge I've change the title for you. I'm surprised that you can't change the title
